# openam client sdk session id invalid

Tags: java, opensso, openam

iam using openam with tomcat 7
the following lines always produce exception
               SSOTokenManager manager = SSOTokenManager.getInstance();
               SSOToken ssoToken = manager.createSSOToken(request);

invalid session id

i think there may be a problem with some configuration or something

any help ???

amSSOProvider:09/18/2012 01:18:01:882 PM EEST: Thread[http-bio-9090-exec-151,5,main]
could not create SSOToken from HttpRequest
com.iplanet.dpro.session.SessionException: Invalid session ID.
    at com.iplanet.dpro.session.Session.getSession(Session.java:1062)
    at com.iplanet.sso.providers.dpro.SSOProviderImpl.createSSOToken(SSOProviderImpl.java:92)
    at com.iplanet.sso.SSOTokenManager.createSSOToken(SSOTokenManager.java:241)
    at main.TestServlet2.doGet(TestServlet2.java:48)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:473)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:909)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

com.iplanet.sso.SSOException: Invalid session ID.
    at com.iplanet.sso.providers.dpro.SSOProviderImpl.createSSOToken(SSOProviderImpl.java:111)
    at com.iplanet.sso.SSOTokenManager.createSSOToken(SSOTokenManager.java:241)
    at main.TestServlet2.doGet(TestServlet2.java:48)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:473)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:909)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: com.iplanet.dpro.session.SessionException: Invalid session ID.
    at com.iplanet.dpro.session.Session.getSession(Session.java:1062)
    at com.iplanet.sso.providers.dpro.SSOProviderImpl.createSSOToken(SSOProviderImpl.java:92)

Answer (score 0):

make sure that domain name of your application is related to domain name of openam server
example of this 
if openam domain server like that openam.example.com  so cookie name is .example.com
so your application is also in this domain yourhost.example.com so we can get token from cookie.